# ColdFusion structure initializing many properties at a time

Tags: coldfusion

I have seen ColdFusion 9 code which initializes many properties of a structure at a time.
Here is an example:

```
<!--- 
 pseudo constructor code 
--->
<cfset variables.instance = {
            first_name  = '',
            last_name   = '',
            gender      = '',
            dateofbirth     = ''
            } />
```

Is there a way to do this in `coldfusion MX7` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, this syntax was partially introduced in cf8, and further improved in 9.  MX7 had no such construct available.

Answer (score 6):

What one can do is to create a small util function thus:

```
function structBuild(){
    return arguments;
}
```

Which one can then call, thus:

```
st = structBuild(
    first_name  = '',
    last_name   = '',
    gender      = '',
    dateofbirth = ''
);
```

That pretty much works the same way.  Not as nice by any measure, but it's a handy technique to be aware of.

Comment: +1 to this, with a caveat, depending on whether you care about the case of the struct fields. Some versions of Railo don't preserve case as passed with this construct, so you may run into trouble if the result ends up getting serialized for javascript, for example.